# Tabela ficando com tamanho diferente em varios monitores

Tags: html, css

o mesmnoTenho a seguinte table:

```
 <div id="page-wrapper">
             <table class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 fm-table" >  
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 fm-left"> 
                        <ul class="fm-tree-directory">

                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </div>
```

e um css:

```
.fm-tree-directory {
 max-height: 750px;
 min-height: 750px;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
```

o problema que no footer ta passando em alguns monitores, e em outros fica longe do footer. Como deixar o mesmo tamanho pra o rodapé sempre, pois a tabela fica com tamanhos diferente sempre.JA tentei definir percentagem minima e maxima, mas não tem efeito.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro o problema, pois o código passado não deixa claro aonde é o footer e os detalhes do problema em questão. Recomendo adicionar mais informações. Acho que seria mais adequado se você não usasse tabelas para fazer o layout do site.

Comment: é um template pronto, e o footer q falo é o final da pagina mesmo, na ocriei nenhuma div. mas queria um espaço pra colocar as credenciais etc. a tabela fica ou grande passando ou sobrando.

Comment: lembrando que o controle do tamanho é exatamente nesse css que lhe passei, pelo menos alterando la no min e max funciona, mas quero algo q funcione em varios monitores.

Comment: eu também não entendi direito o que está acontecendo, você tentou colocar um box-sizing pra ver se fica certo?

Comment: o tamanho da tabela, diferente em varios monitores passando em baixo, esse box-sizing como usa? coloquei initial e nada ocorre.

Comment: Da uma pesquisada sobre o box-sizing, mas caso queira testar coloca no css *{box-sizing-border:box;}

Comment: Postei aqui: jsfiddle.net/2a81bL4e ,Joguei todo codigo do css do bootstrap tbm. veja que a tabela ta entrando la em baixo naquelas informações e se maximizar fica um buraco gigante, as informações o footer deveria ficar fora, em qualquer monitor com um tamanho definido. Acho que tenho que atribuir em algum local height:100%

Comment: Boa noite, se faça está pergunta: *Por que usar tabelas para layout?* A resposta deveria ser algo como: *tabelas são preferíveis para dados tabulares*. :)

Comment: Porque peguei algo pronto, eu jamais uso em layout isso, nao foi feito por mim, so quero corrigir esse bug, e preciso o quanto antes.

Comment: Qual a seria a melhor forma de migrar isso, com bootstrap, pra obter o mesmo resultado? tem como vc editar la no fiddle?

Comment: Como pode ver eu respondi, mas você não me deu um retorno, se deu certo ou não, gostaria de saber amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu ver o uso de tabelas para layouts é um pouco complexo e não é considerado apropriado, principalmente se usar estas classes do [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) que são feitas para o uso de elementos como `div` (`block` ou `inline-block`).

> Note que no [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) também tem classes para tabelas, mas são todas para dados tabulares.

### O que é Tableless

*Tableless* é uma maneira de desenvolver páginas html/xhtml sem utilizar tabelas para disposição de conteúdo na página sugerido pela que foi sugerido pelo [W3C em 2002](http://www.w3.org/2002/03/csslayout-howto), pois defende que os códigos HTML deveriam ser usados para o propósito que foram criados, sendo que tabelas foram criadas para exibir dados tabulares. Para a disposição da página o recomendado seria usar CSS combinado com elementos do tipo `<div>` para dividir o layout e `<span>` para elementos `inline` como formatação de texto, fora outras tags.

*Fonte:* http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless

### Possível solução

Se o seu html é só isto mesmo, recomendo mudar tudo para tags usadas para layout (no caso irei fornecer um exemplo só com DIVs):

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 fm-table">  
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 fm-left"> 
            <ul class="fm-tree-directory">
               <li>Olá mundo</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** Porém não você só postou parte do CSS e do HTML, então não temos como testar. Se não der certo edite a sua pergunta.

Comment: Boa tarde @WarLock funcionou?

Comment: "Ao meu ver o uso de tabelas para layouts é um pouco complexo". Não apenas isso, é simplesmente perca de tempo usar tabelas para layout. Se a evolução da web foi marcada pelo fim do uso delas, por que voltar à época das cavernas?